# Conditional types and infer in typescript to reduce redux boilerplate

Tags: typescript, redux

Sorry if this question is ill-posed, but i'm stuck trying to figure out how to do this. As described in the titel, I'm trying to reduce boilerplate in redux. Here's the issue:

I have `ApiUtils.ts`, and my actions `ApiActions` (and later, `ApiReducer`, but that's a separate issue).

My `ApiUtils` largely have functions that look like this:

```
export function updateUserAPI(id: string, data: Partial<User>) {
  return axios.put<User>(`${usersUrl}/${id}`, data)
}
```

My question is that given that i am using `creatAction` from https://github.com/piotrwitek/typesafe-actions#createaction, I'd like to automate some of this and provide type safety.

Right now, setting up actions looks something like this:

```
export const updateUser = createAction('UPDATE_USER', resolve => (user: Partial<User>) => resolve({ user }))
```

ie, i would like to have something of the form: `function createApiAction<fn> { ... }` where I can provide the ApiUtils.updateUserAPI and it would then it would infer the signature for `resolve => (user: Partial<User>) => resolve({ user})` parameter.

I'm not really sure how to go about this. I've been playing with the tuple args from typescript 3.0+ and `infer`, but that's not sure how to tie them together to get what I want

Comment: Could you please give more details on the ideal signature for your `createApiAction` function?

Comment: Ended up realizing I could use createStandardAction to get most of what I want :) https://github.com/piotrwitek/typesafe-actions/blob/master/src/create-standard-action.ts

Comment: I think what I wanted for createApiFunction was a higher-order function that would infer the `Params<typeof ApiFunc>` and then generate the resolver, ie `resolve => (args: Params<typeof ApiFunc>) => resolve(args)`. but ideally while preserving the parameter names, ie `{id: string, user:User}` as opposed to `[Id, User]`